# Prevent '$.post' calls from outsiders Javascript PHP

Tags: javascript, php, post, spam-prevention, browser-console

I am building a site that calls an email function in order to send emails.

I call a function from external Javascript file with via $.post like the following example:

```
$.post('http://[mydomain]/email.php', {
    'Email': 'email@email.com',
    'Subject': 'This is the subject',
    'Text': 'This is the body'
}, function (data) {

});
```

But as recently noticed, anyone can write the above line to a browser console and send any email they want (using my email address of course).

So my question is:

Is there any way I can recognize this outside calls and prevent them from executing?

Comment: you can check reference. From where the call is from.

Comment: Simple answer, don't do it on the front-end part...

Comment: @urfusion that's a good start, but it still won't stop someone from opening console and calling that line manually while visiting the page, i think.

Comment: @TimothyGroote Yes, That's true.

Comment: Are you guys serious? Doing sensitive operations on front-end? Really?

Comment: which type of request is it from the frontend . Is it an ajax call ?

Comment: `$.post` is ajax...

Answer (score 1):

To make this clear once and for all:

1. You cannot (or maybe should not) put restrictions on what the user types in the console
2. Your problem is not really that users can type your command in the console, it has to do with the fact that you send emails via the front-end part of your website ...

Sensitive operations like sending emails, checking passwords, registering user should **NEVER** be executed on the front-end side of your website ; they should **ALWAYS** be executed on the back-end side of your website. This is common sense when it comes to security risks.